# How to fix 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: .htaccess

i'm getting error "302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Only 1 file in the folder get this error others is fine.

this is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1[R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on that file?

Comment: yes permission is  644

Comment: I know this is from 4 years ago, but did you ever solve the error?? (for science...)